# Robo copy errors

Tags: robocopy

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here but that is why I am here. Any help would be appreciated.

I run the command:

```
robocopy "\\okee01.ini.org\D2 Temp\Fonts 7.10\T^&E\"  "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe InDesign CC 2017\Fonts\"
```

This is the output

```
Started : Wednesday, July 12, 2017 3:09:02 PM Source - \\okee01.ini.org\D2 Temp\Fonts 7.10\T^&E" C:\Program\ Dest - C:\Users\pcoleman\Files\Adobe\Adobe\ Files : InCopy ------------------------------------------------------------‌​------------------ ERROR : Invalid Parameter #5 : "2017\Fonts""
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Started : Wednesday, July 12, 2017 3:09:02 PM
   Source - \\okee01.ini.org\D2 Temp\Fonts 7.10\T^&E" C:\Program\
     Dest - C:\Users\pcoleman\Files\Adobe\Adobe\
    Files : InCopy
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR : Invalid Parameter #5 : "2017\Fonts""

Comment: You should edit your question to add more detail instead to comment your own question

Answer (score 0):

It was due to the double quotations. I removed the first set and it works just fine.